# Add a label to a point of a bubble graph (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bubble-chart, chart.js2

I am having difficulty adding a label to points on my bubble graph.

I am trying to assign the same label as the legend for each of my datasets.

I have tried to assign these points a label, but I seem to only be able to display it's value.

I would like to display the value of the point above and a custom label below the point (Like in the second image below).

[What my current progress is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py3Pf.png)

[What I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bghqw.png)

Here is the code for my progress so far on the chart.

```
<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

    type: 'bubble',

    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Top',
                data: [
                    {x: 110, y: 0, r: 10, name: "Performance"}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
            },
            {
                label: 'Average',
                data: [
                    {x: 75, y: 0, r: 10, name: "Performance"}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
            },
            {
                label: 'You 2017',
                data: [
                    {x: 55, y: 0, r: 10, name: "Performance"}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)"
            },
            {
                label: 'You 2018',
                data: [
                    {x: 90, y: 0, r: 10, name: "Performance"} // The labe needs to be
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,128,0.6)"
            }
        ]
    },
    pointDot : true,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor: function (context) {
                    var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
                },
                align: function (context) {
                    var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
                },
                color: function (context) {
                    var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return value.x < 1000 ? context.dataset.backgroundColor : 'white';
                },
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: function (value) {
                    return Math.round(value.x);
                },
                offset: 2,
                padding: 0
            }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'first-y-axis',
                type: 'linear',
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    display: false
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [
                {
                    id: 'first-x-axis',
                    ticks: {
                        min: 50, // Controls where axis starts
                        max: 120, // Controls where axis finishes
                        stepSize: 70 // Control the gap between the first x-axis value and the last x-axis value
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        lineWidth: 3 // Width of bottom line
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    }

});

</script>
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your datalabels plugin configuration this way:

```
   datalabels: {
        anchor: function (context) {
            var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
        },
        align: function (context) {
            var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
        },
        color: function (context) {
            var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value.x < 1000 ? context.dataset.backgroundColor : 'white';
        },
        font: {
            weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: function (value, context) {
            return context.dataset.label;
        },
        offset: 2,
        padding: 0
    }
```

The [formatter](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/formatting.html) has also a `context` parameter which contains info about dataset like label.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/3ed8t6pe/

Comment: This worked great! Do you know how I could align it below?

Comment: Wait figured it out you can set it to 'start' : 'center'; under the anchor and alignment settings